# Is "vary" a stative verb? Can it be used in Continuous?

Tags: grammar

Is "vary" a stative verb?

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vary) it has both intransitive

> **vary** [intransitive]
>
> 1: to exhibit or undergo change
>
> - *the sky was constantly varying*

and transitive usages

> **vary** [transitive]
>
> 1: to make a partial change in: make different in some attribute or
> characteristic
> ...
>
> - *I try to vary my diet by eating different kinds of foods.*

Can it be used in Continuous? I didn't find any examples.

Comment: Intriguing. That something varies (or *is varying,* or *is variable*) might be a state of being, even though varying is as much an action as running.

Comment: Did you google "is varying" (with quotation marks)? When I did so, I got many examples.

Comment: I'd say the transitive usage here, 'I vary my diet' synonymous with 'I keep making changes to my diet' is iterative rather than stative. // 'Constantly varying' might be arguably iterative (undergoing repeated changes one after the other) or stative (in flux); it's possible that some linguists would want an entirely different classification.

Comment: _Was constantly varying_ is Continuous (aka Progressive). And it's not stative, especially not in its causative usage.